# Is $P_n$ closed in $L^2[(0,1)]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $P_n$ is the set of polynomial functions of degree less than or equal to $n$, then is it closed in $L^2([0,1])?$ How would we go about showing this? Thanks!

Comment: Show more generally that any finite-dimensional subspace is closed.  Use the fact that it is complete...

Comment: ... By using that all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.